# C#: Swagger/Swashbuckle - Connect security schemes with "AND"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an ASP.NET Core Api where it is required to use multiple authentication schemes for one operation. I am trying to document those operations with displaying all required authentication schemes in Swagger UI.
Therefore I use the **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (5.1.0)** library for a dynamic adding of `OpenApiSecurityRequirement` to the `OpenApiOperation` in an `IOperationFilter`:

```
if (authorizeAttributes.Any(x => x.AuthenticationSchemes.Contains(InternalControllerBasicAuthentication.AuthenticationScheme)))
{
       requirements.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
       {
             {
                   new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "credentials"
                        }
                   },
                   new [] { "Basic <credentials-value>" }
             }
      });
} 

if (authorizeAttributes.Any(x => x.AuthenticationSchemes.Contains(OneTimePasswordAuthentication.AuthenticationScheme)))
{
      requirements.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
      {
             {
                   new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "one-time-password"
                        }
                   },
                   new [] { "Basic <one-time-password-value>" }
             }
      });
}

operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>(requirements);
```

Furthemore I use the `SwaggerGenOptions` to register all possible schemes:

```
var oneTimePasswordScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Name = "one-time-password",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Scheme = "one-time-password",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
};

options.AddSecurityDefinition("one-time-password", oneTimePasswordScheme);

var credentialsScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Name = "credentials",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Scheme = "credentials",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
};

options.AddSecurityDefinition("credentials", credentialsScheme);
```

Everything works fine except for Swagger using the `OR` connector in the UI:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Swagger using the `AND` connector?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding a `OpenApiSecurityRequirement` for each `OpenApiSecurityScheme`, it is necessary to put all `OpenApiSecurityScheme` objects into a single `OpenApiSecurityRequirement`.

Connects security requirements with **OR**:

```
var requirements = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>();
requirements.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "scheme-1"
            }
        },
        new [] { "scheme-1-value" }
    }
});

requirements.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "scheme-2"
            }
        },
        new [] { "scheme-2-value" }
    }
});

operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>(requirements);
```

Connects security requirements with **AND**:

```
var requirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
requirement.Add(new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference {
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
            Id = "scheme-1"
        }
    },
    new [] { "scheme-1-value" }
);

requirement.Add(new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference {
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
            Id = "scheme-2"
        }
    },
    new [] { "scheme-2-value" }
);

operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement> { requirement };
```